# Highcharts - column chart redraw animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to update an existing data series with a new data array and invoke the `redraw` function when done. While this works perfectly, I'm not quite satisfied as I'd like to have a sort of grow/shrink transition. I have seen an [example by Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/studies/dynamic.htm) (fiddle around with the existing data set then click on the button *"Set new data to selected series"*) but I can't replicate this behavior.

This is what code that I've written:

```
  var series, newSeriesThreshold = this.chart.series.length * 2;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
    series = {
      name:  this.data[i].title,
      data:  this.data[i].data,
      color: this.data[i].color
    };

    if (i >= newSeriesThreshold) {
      this.chart.addSeries(series, false);
    } else {
      var currentSeries = this.chart.series[i / 2];
      currentSeries.setData(series.data, false);
    }
  }

  this.chart.redraw();
```

These are the options when creating the chart:

```
  var config = {
    chart: {
      renderTo: $(this.container).attr('id'),
      type: this.settings.type,
      animation: {
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'swing'
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: this.settings.legend.show
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.x.toFixed(0) + ": <b>" + this.y.toString().toCurrency(0) + '</b>';
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      title: {
        text: this.settings.xaxis.title,
        style: {
          color: '#666'
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: this.settings.yaxis.title,
        style: {
          color: '#666'
        }
      }
    },
    series: series,
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        color: '#FF7400'
      }
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    }
  };
```

This yields an immediate update without transitioning effects. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What's the error ? Can you log your data response to see if it's the expected value ?

Comment: There is no error. The chart is just updated with the new values without any transition effects. Stepping through the source code, `doAnimation = animation && series.animate` yields `false` as `series.animate` is null!

Comment: I didn't need to do a redraw to see the updated data, but I too am wondering why there is no transition effect on column charts.

Comment: here is the answer:  

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16011343/1356019  
it's work for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This remain a mystery. I managed to make the axis update which suggests that there is some kind of animation going on, but it's applied only to the axis, and not the columns.

In the end, I've settled with this behavior.

Comment: Hello Zanathel, I have the same problem with you. Just want animation when data updated. So right now Do you have good solution? I am trying but cannot find the answer

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem by destroying and creating again the chart.

Here is the link on highcharts forum that helps me : http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/animation-on-redraw-t8636/#p93199

The answer comes from the highcharts support team.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var chartOptions = {
                    // Your chart options
                    series: [
                             {name: 'Serie 1' , color: '#303AFF', data: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
                            ]
                };

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);

        $("#my_button").click(function(){ 
            chart.destroy();
            chartOptions.series[0].data = [10,5,2,10,5,2,10];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```js
var mychart = $("#mychart").highcharts();     
var height = mychart.renderTo.clientHeight; 
var width = mychart.renderTo.clientWidth; 
mychart.setSize(width, height);
```

to update all charts

```js
$(Highcharts.charts).each(function(i,chart){
    var height = chart.renderTo.clientHeight; 
    var width = chart.renderTo.clientWidth; 
    chart.setSize(width, height); 
  });
```