# Highcharts loading animation after setdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using Highcharts graphs and I am using .setData to update the data in the graph.

This is all working fine but I would like to use the loading animation (where the line chart draws itself from left to right) to be triggered every time I reset the data. Is there a way to call this animation?

Comment: by default, it should animate i think.. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.animation, can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 10):

You can remove actual series, and add new one. Initial animation is different from all others (clip path is animated, not series itself).

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/UTC6e/2/

```
    chart.series[0].remove();
    chart.addSeries({data:[229.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4]} );
```

Comment: Problem with this is that it moves the placement of the series.

Comment: Could you explain? And add a live example?

Answer (score 6):

In the [api reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setVisible%28%29) I see the method setVisible(): "A utility function to show or hide the series with an optional redraw.". I think that's what you're looking for?

UPDATE: added JS Fiddle, see: http://jsfiddle.net/UTC6e/1/

So you could first setVisible to false, then set the new data, and at the end setVisible to true and tell the chart to redraw (second boolean argument).

```
chart.series[0].setVisible(false);
chart.series[0].setData([229.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4] );
chart.series[0].setVisible(true, true);
```

Comment: This is close to what i am looking for but not excately what i mean. When you click run you you can see that the graphs gets drawn. When i click set data a whole new dataset gets loaded and I want it to get redrawn in the same way as the graph initially gets drawn

Answer (score 0):

You could just manually call the redraw method:

```
chart.redraw();
```