# Animation for dynamically loaded new data with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, animation, highcharts

I have to switch between two data sets on a line chart, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0722yy2c/13/). One has a linear x-axis and the other one a logarithmic x-axis. Updating the data is no problem doing:

```
chart.series[0].setData( data2, false);
chart.xAxis[0].update({type: "logarithmic"}, false);
chart.redraw();
```

The problem is that the **transition** between data **not animated**. From data set 1 to data set 2, the plot jumps, but oddly, showing the data **in opposite order**, first set 2, then set 1, **is animated**.

In the reference [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData), they say something about a third argument for `setData()` for animating when setting new data with different length, but setting this to `true` or `{duration: x}` did not work.

EDIT:

Thank you for your responses so far, but apparently I didn't explained it clear enough, but to get what I mean, you should look closely at the animations in the fiddle I linked to. Compare the animation when you click on data set 2 (the transitions is not animated), and then click on the other button to go back to the initial data set (you will see an animated transition). **If Highcharts can animate the transition from set 2 to 1, why can't it also display the same animation in reverse from set 1 to 2 using the same code?**

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/0722yy2c/14/  I am a little confused on your question.

Comment: It's better, but I think what you did is animating the switch from linear to logarithmic scale, and not the transition from old to new points. If I comment out the line for logarithmic scale in your answer, I get no transition animation at all.

Comment: Use the series.update() for both cases (instead of setData), then you achieve the same effect. http://jsfiddle.net/0722yy2c/16/

Comment: @SebastianBochan Ok, that gives indeed the same effect, but not the transitions animation where you see the curve change of shape. Now the curve shape is not animated at all, only the change of scale on the axes is.

Comment: Unfortuantely at this moment these animations are defaulty. You can try to remove serie and apply new one, as Nishith mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this [Highcharts loading animation after setdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987283/highcharts-loading-animation-after-setdata)

Important point I found by an answer given by Highcharts Champ Sebastian is :
**animations after setData()  is not available in highcharts**

So you should remove existing series using chart.destroy and then create new to see animation working on that.

```
chart.series[0].remove();
chart.addSeries({data:[yourData]}) //and other values like type etc
```

For Default Animation Try This

```
   chart: {
        animation: {
            duration: 2000, //whatever you want
            easing: 'easeOutBounce'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but this is unfortunately not what I'm looking for. What you describe is how to get the 'initial data animation' from left to right, not the transition where you see the curve move to it's new form. What you quoted from Sebastian seems relevant though. Can you point me out where you found this?