# Highcharts load effect on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

Here is a highchart sample fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-setdata/

```
$('#button').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        // I want the code which will have the effect of line being drawn on points, just like when clicked on run in the above fiddle link.
});
```

If you check the fiddle when you click on run the there is an animation where the line is drawn from left to right. I am looking for a similar method where when i click on a button the highchart will redraw itself with the same data. I have multiple charts like column and pie on my project, i have tried reflow and redraw but both have their own purposes and do not satisfy my requirement. Please help.

Comment: Maybe you can remove your series and add new one with the same parameters that previous series? http://jsfiddle.net/fdwwv3ey/

Answer (score 1):

Use "animation" in chart config:

```
  animation: {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'easeOutBounce'
    }
```

Comment: It is not working as i am expecting, i have also looked it up http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.animation , the animation example here shows data being updated. My data remains the same, i only want the effect of line being drawn again.

Comment: fine! Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188114/highcharts-column-chart-redraw-animation  and the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/my8646oc/31/

Comment: I am still looking for a better way to get it working , but the link you have sent does solve my problem for now.